# App is crashing while clicking on app icon

Tags: android

I installed the app through android studio and its working fine, but when I create the apk and then I installed the apk, on some devices my app is crashing.

Can someone know how we can see the logs or errors in case when we installed through apk, in can't debug the app bcos its working that time.

here are few details,
build variant: debug,

my apk name: app-debug.apk,

and I am using 2 3rd party libs as an .aar files

Comment: Nobody can help you out if you don't share the log and suspicious code/build problem.

Comment: Hello.  I recommend you to use crashlytics https://try.crashlytics.com/ you can use it with a release and get detail of every crash.

Comment: What the code fragment you suspect is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed the apk also you can able to get the logs if you have connected your device with studio. For that you have set the **No Filter** in **Android Monitor**.[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the phones, your app is crashing, don't just install the app by apk there. May be some of your 3rd party dependency is not compatible with those versions or phones.

Debug your app in those phone with cable and check error logs. You will get to know the problem